# How can I get to the STATIC animalType, from a generic type?

Tags: typescript

Given the following example code, I would like to get to the value of the generic, static, animalType in T.animalType, how can one approach this?

```
export class main {

    constructor() {

        var myWorker: worker = new worker();
        myWorker.whatAmI();

    }

}

export class worker extends workerBase<dog> {

}

export class workerBase<T extends animal>
{
    public whatAmI() {
        //output animal type as "dog"
        console.warn("Animal type: " + T.animalType); // <<-- this will NOT work, but this is what I want to achieve
    }
}

export class animal {
    public static animalType: string = "any";
}

export class dog extends animal {
    public static animalType: string = "dog";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic types are not available at run time, and neither are the types because javascript has no notion of types.

For example:

```
class A<T> {
    private x: number;

    constructor(x: number) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Compiles into:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    return A;
}());
```

And as you can see the type of x (`number`) isn't in the compiled js, and neither is the `T`.

What you can do is:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract getType(): string;
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    getType(): string {
        return "dog"; 
    }
}

class MyClass<T extends Animal> {
    private animal: T;

    constructor(animal: T) {
        this.animal = animal;
        console.log(`animal type: ${ this.animal.getType() }`)
    }
}

let dog = new Dog();
let a = new MyClass(dog); // animal type: dog
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20getType()%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Dog%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20getType()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20%22dog%22%3B%20%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20Animal%3E%20%7B%0A%09private%20animal%3A%20T%3B%0A%09%0A%09constructor(animal%3A%20T)%20%7B%0A%09%09this.animal%20%3D%20animal%3B%0A%09%09console.log(%60animal%20type%3A%20%24%7B%20this.animal.getType()%20%7D%60)%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20dog%20%3D%20new%20Dog()%3B%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20MyClass(dog)%3B%20%2F%2F%20animal%20type%3A%20dog))

Comment: Thanks for the input - in your scenario I would need to instantiate animal to pass it into the MyClass constructor. I am looking for a solution where I can go  static e.g. console.log(`animal type: ${ T.getType() }`)

Comment: As I wrote, you can't do that. `T` does not exist in run time. You can pass the class `Dog` to the ctor of `MyClass` and have a static method on it, but it's not a good solution because static functions are don't play nice with OO principles.  Maybe if you'll explain more about you actual scenario I (or someone else) can find a better solution that fits what you need.

Comment: Well sometimes if you cant do something - you cant do it. I did some further reading around, its not possible to access the static of a generic in C# either. It would be nice new feature though. I'll give you the answer because the answer is -> it cant be done.

Comment: It's probably doable in Scala